# What can I use for interior helmet padding?

Tags: helmets, diy

My bike helmet needs more padding on the inside.

Any suggestions of what to use?

I"m thinking double sided tape and some sort of neoprene or other cushiony material.

Comment: Not a good idea! The helmet should fit without extra padding that is not factory approved. Risk of injury!

Comment: @Carel plenty of manufacturers sell fine-tuning upgrades, and they're made of very soft town. Other helmets come with a variety of thicknesses of foam including quite thick. Even if the parts are factory approved the fitting is beyond their control, so a diy approach is feasible. Keep the foam soft though - it's only there to make it fit, not as part of the protective padding. The risk is a lawyers risk rather than a real one, *unlike modifications to the shell*. Ill-fitting helmets are a greater risk and most helmets lack much adjustment for *shape* as opposed to size.

Comment: I suspect you'd void any warramty that the helmet adheres to e.g. safety standards. Do you care?

Comment: I use "mini-pads" -- the "feminine hygiene" product.  They're absorbent, reasonably cheap, and have an adhesive strip that makes them easy to install inside the helmet.  (Mostly I use these to simply absorb sweat, but have used them to "resize" a loaned helmet on several occasions.)

Answer (score 4):

I have used some half-inch thick strips of foam to help raise the helmet

You need to add the foam where there is a void between your scalp and the helmet.   It should **not** be added where the helmet presses on your head.

Small amount should not mess up how the helmet works.  Its no different to going from a long haircut to a short haircut.

In winter I wear a thin beanie under my helmet.  Some people wear bandannas or cycling caps.

If its a really bad fit you might want to replace it.   Why did you buy it if its a bad fit?   ***Do not mail-order helmets site-unseen!!!***

Comment: You actually suggest a reason for a bad fit yourself: a significant haircut.